# How to send build artifacts over ssh using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I was using Freestyle project method for configuring jobs in Jenkins. I have used Publish Over SSH plugin to send war file to remote system. Now i moved to pipeline configuration. I would like to know how can i do the same in pipeline configuration. Can anyone tell how to write pipeline script for publish over ssh?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the raw Unix command `scp`, as described there : [Example syntax for SCP](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php). scp is Unix utility for secure copy... over SSH, which is exactly what [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin#PublishOverSSHPlugin-Features) uses behind the scenes !

Example :

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have tried it. I'm getting an exception in Jenkins. It saying Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\testmailservice"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.I think it's because  I am using windows system and my remote is ubuntu.

Comment: You can try using jenkins pipelines `ssh-agent`, see the [documentation here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)

Comment: is there a way to run command "echo transfer success" after publish over ssh operation completes ?. I want to do so to check status of transferred files